# Why is my worker working in a wrong thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a class `Messenger` with two internal object pointers:

```cpp
    std::unique_ptr<QThread> stdin_receiver_thread_ = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<ReceiverWorker> stdin_receiver_ = nullptr;
```

In the constructor of the `Messenger` I create these objects and assign them to these smart pointers like so:

```cpp
Messenger::Messenger(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {

    // create the objects
    stdin_receiver_thread_ = std::make_unique<QThread>(); 
    stdin_receiver_ = std::make_unique<ReceiverWorker>();
    //
    qDebug() << "stdin_receiver_thread_:" << stdin_receiver_thread_.get()->thread();

    // I assign the worker to this the newly created thread
    stdin_receiver_->moveToThread(stdin_receiver_thread_.get());
    //

    connect(stdin_receiver_thread_.get(), &QThread::started, stdin_receiver_.get(), &ReceiverWorker::process);
    connect(stdin_receiver_.get(), &ReceiverWorker::receivedMessage, stdin_receiver_thread_.get(), &QThread::quit);
    connect(stdin_receiver_.get(), &ReceiverWorker::receivedMessage, stdin_receiver_.get(), &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(stdin_receiver_thread_.get(), &QThread::finished, stdin_receiver_thread_.get(), &QObject::deleteLater);

    stdin_receiver_thread_->start();
}
```

and inside my `ReceiverWorker::process()`
i call

```cpp
qDebug() << "Receiverworker currentThread:" << QThread::currentThread();
```

Now, those two `qDebug()` calls print different values: i.e.:

```
stdin_receiver_thread_: QThread(0x20a24e57ba0)
Receiverworker currentThread: QThread(0x20a2e6f58e0)
```

so it's like ReceiverWorker works in some different thread than I want it to. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing exactly what it should. The term `stdin_receiver_thread_.get()->thread();` yields the `QThread` in which `stdin_receiver_thread_` as a `QObject` lives. In other terms your main thread or wherever `Messenger` was constructed.

If you had instead just written:

```
qDebug() << "stdin_receiver_thread_:" << stdin_receiver_thread_.get();
```

you would have gotten the expected output.

---

```
std::unique_ptr<QThread>
```

You should not be using `std::unique_ptr` with a `QObject` for which you call `deleteLater()`. That inevitably results in a double-free / heap corruption.

Comment: Hah, what a fast anwer. Thank you. I was doing JS recently and got addicted to chaining calls and wrote this without thinking. Thank you again, for such fast and brief answer.

Comment: Should I just use raw pointers instead? Or resign from deleteLater?

Comment: Yes, raw pointers might just work. Or the QT smart pointers which release themselves when a `QObject` is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling QObject::thread() on a QThread object. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread) say: "Returns the thread in which the object lives." The QThread is an object that lives in the main thread. I think your function is working as expected, you just weren't comparing the right values for your qDebugs.